# Facebook authorization message appears differently

Tags: iphone, facebook

I am using Facebook authorization in our app and am receiving a different authorization screen than all the other apps in the market. Does anybody know why it would be displaying differently?

[image: My App]

[image: Other Apps]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [new open graph extended auth dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/authentication/) and you can enable it on your app settings page.